Should the price of a vanilla option be the Weighted average probabilistic payoff?
I was reading Ricardo Rebonato's "Volatility and Correlation: The Perfect Hedger and the Fox".
In chapter two he is discussing pricing a contingent claim via replication and then also by what he calls "Naive expectation", this is where I had a question. I had always thought that if you were given the true probability distribution of the underlying, the price of an vanilla option would be the integral from the strike to either infinity or zero (depending on call or put) discounted by the risk free rate. Essentially, the price of an option = the probabilistic weighted average payoff at expiration (ignore early exercise for the moment). Is this not true?
My reading of Rebonato's book seems to imply that it's not. He says this in chapter 2:
"One could be tempted to speculate, on the basis of the extra piece of information we have now that the 'fair price' of the contingent claim today should be equal to the weighted average of the two possible outcomes C1 and C2, appropriately discounted by the rate implied by the riskless bond...A moment's reflection, however, shows that the expectation calculated on the basis of the probabilities we know to apply in the real world to events w1 and w2 must in general produce a value different from the fair price obtained using the replication strategy."
He further goes on to say that since the probabilities in no way depend on the replication strategy, it would be an enormous coincidence if the prices actually lined up like this.
I was hoping someone could clarify this a bit for me. Is my understanding of probabilities and options pricing correct and I am just misinterpreting what Rebonato is saying here?

Condider a game that pays $2 with known probability of 50%. Would you pay $1, the expected value, to play it? Perhaps, or perhaps you're too risk averse and don't want ro risk losing any money, or perhaps conversely you're willing to pay even more for a chance to win the $2.

So you're talking about investor risk preferences then right? Some investors might be risk seeking or risk averse. Is it then fair to say that in a risk neutral universe, where investors only care about expected value this is how options would be priced?

@DimitriVulis in your example also, $1 is the "correct" theoretical answer right? If I could play such a game repeatedly for 99 cents, I would surely do it.

The "correct" fair prices are whatever the market participants would pay, and those may be driven by participants' risk appetite, marginal utility, views on the actual probability, and many other factors... in real life, an actual probability is often not observable, but some market quotes are observable, and from them you could find the risk-neutral model parameters, and interpolate those.

@JacksonSmith: I think you are possibly confusing the "real world" and the "risk-neutral" probability. This answer here might help to clarify.

Maybe take a step back from options and look at futures.
Say you know that an asset (currently worth $100\\\$$ returns (in expectation) $6\%$ over the next year (or you know the real world probability distribution) and the risk free rate (which you can borrow and lend at) is $4\%$.
What would the price of the future on that asset be?
By using the expectation of the real world distribution you would get $106 \\\$$. This is what the asset is worth in expectation. But this would open up arbitrage:
If you value the future at $106\\\$$, everybody is happy to sell it to you. The seller would then borrow $100\\\$$ and buy the asset. Then sell the asset to you for $106\\\$$ in one year. Using the proceeds he would proceed to pay off the debt (and interested) ($-104\\\$$) and nets a risk free profit of $2$.
In this case you would have to use the risk neutral probability distribution (with mean equal to the risk free rate), despite your knowledge that this is not the "real world" mean.
The case for options is not that straightforward. For example Black-Scholes needs some more restrictions on the underlying distribution to allow dynamic hedging, but the underlying idea stays the same.
There are other scenarios, where you can show that you need to use a risk neutral distribution and not the real world/physical one.

You have the correct interpretation.  The naive expectation does not produce the correct price.  An enormous amount of literature in this subject is available on this site and elsewhere.  Look for ‘risk-neutral pricing’.

To me, the key idea is that when you take the expectation you cannot use "the probabilities we know apply in the real world", but some other, modified probabililties (or if you prefer pseudo-probabilities or risk-neutrl probabilities). Yes, you take an expectation, but not the way most people do it, there is an extra step first.

@dm63 I see, I'm somewhat familiar with risk neutral pricing as it tends to come up in finance a lot. The gist of it being, that a risk neutral investor would be indifferent between a coinflip where heads he wins 2, and tails he loses 1, and a coinflip game where heads he wins 1,000,002 and tails he loses, 1,000,000,001. As both have the same expected value? Do I have that right? Are you saying then, that prices reflect the true probability distribution + some adjustment for risk aversion?

@nbbo2 I appreciate your comment. I suppose I set the question in a bit of a roundabout way because I said "assume we have the true distribution". I should clarify, I'm doing this because I'm generating probabilities by hand, and then using those to price options, and then backing out implied volatility skew. I'm doing this to better understand volatility skew and what it means exactly if say the slope of the skew increases by 3 points per strike. I was hoping this way, I could gain some intuition, but you're saying my methodology is flawed?
